# Getting sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near "INSERT": syntax error only on ICS 4.0.4 but working fine in android kitkat 4.4.4

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

getting sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near "INSERT": syntax error only on ICS 4.0.4 but working fine in android kitkat 4.4.4

```
12-27 11:39:35.468: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(17406): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near "INSERT": syntax error, db=/data/data/com.example.sample/databases/database.db
    12-27 11:39:35.469: W/System.err(17406): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "INSERT": syntax error
    12-27 11:39:35.484: W/System.err(17406):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_executeSql(Native Method)
    12-27 11:39:35.485: W/System.err(17406):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:93)
    12-27 11:39:35.485: W/System.err(17406):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1900)
    12-27 11:39:35.485: W/System.err(17406):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1839)
    12-27 11:39:35.485: W/System.err(17406):    at utils.DatabaseHandler.onCreate(DatabaseHandler.java:132)
    12-27 11:39:35.485: W/System.err(17406):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:165)
    12-27 11:39:35.485: W/System.err(17406):    at com.example.sample.NotificationProvider.onCreate(NotificationProvider.java:43)
    12-27 11:39:35.485: W/System.err(17406):    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:944)
    12-27 11:39:35.485: W/System.err(17406):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4398)
    12-27 11:39:35.485: W/System.err(17406):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4153)
    12-27 11:39:35.485: W/System.err(17406):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4107)
    12-27 11:39:35.485: W/System.err(17406):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:134)
    12-27 11:39:35.485: W/System.err(17406):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1285)
    12-27 11:39:35.485: W/System.err(17406):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    12-27 11:39:35.485: W/System.err(17406):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    12-27 11:39:35.486: W/System.err(17406):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
    12-27 11:39:35.486: W/System.err(17406):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    12-27 11:39:35.486: W/System.err(17406):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    12-27 11:39:35.486: W/System.err(17406):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
    12-27 11:39:35.486: W/System.err(17406):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
    12-27 11:39:35.486: W/System.err(17406):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Sql code

```
String CREATE_TABLE_TABLENAME = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " 
                + TABLE_TABLENAME + "("+ CL_KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," 
                + CL_KEY_REFID + " INTEGER ,"
                + CL_KEY_DATE + " TEXT ,"
                + CL_KEY_TEXT + " TEXT ,"
                + CL_KEY_TYPE + " TEXT "+")";           
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_TABLENAME);
```

Comment: post your code too please

Comment: edit your question and post your code there......

Comment: Show the code that executes the SQL.

Comment: This does not seem to be the code that causes the problem.

Comment: yes you are right it works fine in kitkat but not in ics, i don't no why.

Comment: Post the complete `utils.DatabaseHandler.onCreate()` and highlight what is row number 132 there.